# Error al consultar Base de datos Remota PHP 7

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un error de tipo 500, al iniciar este código

Al consultar la base de datos mi server solo tiene disponible PHP7 
Según leí puede ser porque mi código sólo funciona con PHP5

El código debería mostrar una serie de consultas, nombres y números pero solo me manda el error 500, **cabe mencionar que otros host gratuitos si funciona**.

```
include_once "includes/variables.php";
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', $host);
DEFINE ('DB_USER', $user);   
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', $pass);
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', $database);

$mysqli = @mysqli_connect ($host,$user, $pass) OR die ('Could not connect to MySQL');
//mysqli_select_db ("DB_NAME") OR die (mysqli_error($mysqli));

   mysqli_select_db($mysqli, 'DB_NAME') or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
//mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

if(isset($_GET['cat_id']))
{

        $query="SELECT image AS 'images', category_name AS 'cat_name', cid FROM tbl_category c, tbl_gallery n WHERE c.cid=n.cat_id and c.cid='".$_GET['cat_id']."' ORDER BY n.id DESC";         
        $resouter = mysql_query($query);

}
else if(isset($_GET['latest']))
{
        $limit=$_GET['latest'];     

        $query="SELECT * FROM tbl_category c,tbl_gallery n WHERE c.cid=n.cat_id ORDER BY n.id DESC LIMIT $limit";           
        $resouter = mysql_query($query);
}
else if(isset($_GET['custom_category']))
{       
        $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_category c, tbl_gallery n WHERE c.cid = n.cat_id AND c.category_name = 'Nature' ORDER BY n.id DESC";            
        $resouter = mysql_query($query);
}
else
{   
        $query="SELECT * FROM tbl_category ORDER BY cid DESC";          
        $resouter = mysql_query($query);
}

$set = array();

$total_records = mysql_num_rows($resouter);
if($total_records >= 1){

  while ($link = mysql_fetch_array($resouter, MYSQL_ASSOC)){

    $set['MaterialWallpaper'][] = $link;
  }
}

 echo $val= str_replace('\\/', '/', json_encode($set));


?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Estás tratando de ejecutar tus querys usando mysql_query, una función que es parte de la extensión php-mysql, y que no existe en PHP7. Por otro lado, no tiendo cómo ese código funciona en otros servers, porque no estás declarando una conexión con el driver adecuado.

En fin. Tus consultas deben tener la forma `$mysqli->query("SELECT ...")`

Por ejemplo, donde dice:

```
$query="SELECT image AS 'images', category_name AS 'cat_name', cid FROM tbl_category c, tbl_gallery n WHERE c.cid=n.cat_id and c.cid='".$_GET['cat_id']."' ORDER BY n.id DESC";         
$resouter = mysql_query($query);
```

debiese decir:

```
$query="SELECT image AS 'images', category_name AS 'cat_name', cid FROM tbl_category c, tbl_gallery n WHERE c.cid=n.cat_id and c.cid='".$_GET['cat_id']."' ORDER BY n.id DESC";         
$resouter = mysqli->query($query);
```

aprovecho de mencionarte que ese código que estás mostrando tiene un serio problema de inyección SQL. Basta manipular el parámetro `cat_id` para inyectar una consulta arbitraria.

Si no tienes tiempo para aprender sobre sentencias preparadas, al menos podrías castear el `cat_id` a integer (si es un número) y usar esa variable en tu query:

```
$cat_id=intval($_GET['cat_id']);
$query="SELECT image AS 'images', category_name AS 'cat_name', cid FROM tbl_category c, tbl_gallery n WHERE c.cid=n.cat_id and c.cid=$catid ORDER BY n.id DESC";         
$resouter = $mysqli->query($query);
```